# Skip directory in msdeploy

Tags: absolute-path, msdeploy, skip

I have a msdeploy in my nant script(Team City) that is working except it is copying some folders that I do not want to copy. What command will skip these directories? I tried:

```
<arg value="-skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=C:\Websites\slingshotportal\Build scripts"' />
and
<arg value='-skip:objectName=contentPath,absolutePath="C:\\Websites\\slingshotportal\\Build scripts"' />
```

None of these commands seem to work and the Build scripts directory is still copied fromm source directory to destination directory? The msbuild does a sync and I specify both -source and -dest as contentPath.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have a TeamCity nant build script and the one that worked for me in the end was:

```
<arg value='-skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="\\published"' />
```

The directory to skip was \published so notice that I had to escape the \ I also found that a directory like webroot\app.domain.feature had to be escaped like: `webroot\\app\.domain\.feature`

Comment: The absolutePath value is a regular expression which is why those characters need to be escaped.

Answer (score 5):

You need to look at the "skip" parameter.

Documentation is available here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no "-skip" parameter in there.